# How to get/use the maximum value of an array

Tags: php

I have and array of numbers which I can retrieve as follows:

```
foreach ($this->items as $item) {
    $this->something += ($this->dels[$item]) ;
}
```

what this does is adds all the `$this->dels[$item]` values up, however I would like to get the highest value from this and then use it. I have tried the following:

```
foreach ($this->items as $item) {
    $this->something = max($this->dels[$item]);
}
```

however this returns `$this->something` = 0
any help welcome

Comment: max comparing 2 values and returns the highest one

Comment: _the highest value from this_ What is **this**?

Comment: If you want the maximum of the array - no need for a loop just `$this->something = max($this->dels) ;`

Comment: @Ria Why are you doing `max($this->dels[$item])` ? Does `$this->dels[$item]` itself contain an array?

Comment: What does `$this->items` contain? Also, your code would overwrite `$this->something` on each iteration, which doesn't make much sense. Please show us what your variables contain and what result you're expecting.

Comment: Just use the creatively named `max()` or `min()` functions.  `what this does is adds all the` - `array_sum()`  - Don't have an array, `(array)$obj` just cast it.

Comment: @Nigel Ren I tried this however it still tuns out 0. I have put in as values 7.99 and nothing else it still shows up as 0

Comment: What is `var_dump($this->items);`?

Comment: _“however I would like to get the highest value from this and then use it”_ - use it for what? Your description of what you are actually trying to achieve here is more than unclear. Using max _inside_ that loop probably makes no sense whatsoever though.

Answer (score 0):

put the array directly into the max function to get maximum value

```
max($this->items);
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the following works:

```
foreach($this->items as $item) {
                $something[] = $this->dels[$item] ;

            }
                $this->something = max($something);
```

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find [max](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-max) from a collection use `$this->items->max()`